# Discord Clear Command role permission doesnt work

Tags: discord, discord.js

I have tried to make a simple discord bot with the command (!clear) with permissions. I want the "Admin perms" role to be the only role allowed to do the !clear command. Every time I try to do the command its says that message.guild.roles.find is not a function. The code I have right now is:

```
switch(args[0]){
    case 'clear':
       if(message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === 'Admin perms')) {

            if(!args[1]) {
               return channel.reply ('How many message do you want me to delete idot!')
            }
       message.channel.bulkDelete(args[1]);
```

Comment: Can you please describe the problem you are having with this code?

Comment: Everytime it starts it says that message.guild.roles.find is not a function

Comment: I'd suggest using `message.member.roles.has("role-id")` instead if this bot is just for a personal server. You get the role id by typing `\` before mentioning the role and pressing enter

Answer (score 2):

```
        if(!message.member.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "Admin perms")) return message.channel.send('You dont have permissions to do that idot!')

    if(!args[1]) return message.reply('How many message do you want me to delete idot!')
    message.channel.bulkDelete(args[1]);
    break;
```